# Reading request data in chunks in-compliance with heap space

Tags: java, heap-memory, spring-webflux

I have a POST-api implemented using Spring-Webflux which takes arrays of objects as request body without any limitation in size of it like 
`{
    "messages": [
        {
            "id": "41f07eb9-40f3-4f31-a049-e561b4bd6f63",
            "value": "Occaecat amet incididunt pariatur laborum nisi duis tempor sint eiusmod consequat officia nisi."
        },
        {
            "id": "ff415d87-8751-467e-b351-6d0b6f963b13",
            "value": "Voluptate laborum veniam incididunt eu irure pariatur amet fugiat fugiat laboris esse enim voluptate in."
        },
        {
            "id": "caddd7e9-0b61-456b-b042-26a14c22cfb8",
            "value": "Fugiat cupidatat quis velit proident magna quis enim pariatur do qui magna ea excepteur ea."
        }
    ..
    ..... and so on]
   }` and processes it, now what I want to do is, process the incoming request body in a stream manner, Is there a way I can consume APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE in my POST API? Example would be something like this:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public DemoMessage addToDB(@RequestBody DemoRequest demoRequest) {
   // delegate to some logic
}
```

My main intent is to save heap-space by not loading the whole payload and instead process it in stream manner, one by one. Any suggestions or help would be hold in high regards. Thanks!

Any suggestions/ideas on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add some code snippets, maybe a sample request body? This is too vague.

Comment: Hi @BrianClozel, I've updated the question with how request-body looks like where I want to process all the entries but without ever exceeding the heap-limit.